# Angular $http request issue

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to retreive some images from a flickr service [this one](https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/).
Unfortunately, i have the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json. 

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 

Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here's my code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('getFlickrImages', function($http){
    this.getData = function() {
      delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json'
         });
     }

  });

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, getFlickrImages) {
      $scope.data = null;
      getFlickrImages.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
       $scope.data = dataResponse;
   });
  });
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xCb8hgQuaL1z5X63WIaE?p=preview) if someone can help me

Comment: It's not about your code, this error message means the API server doesnt allow you to use it. Try to find something about test in the doc, maybe they opened a route for it

Comment: I try without angular in pure javascript and it's working

Comment: When you try it in pure javascript, do you execute it on http://localhost:3000 or just with your browser ?

Comment: Just with the browser

Comment: So the problem is your server localhost, I don't know this API, but maybe you should have a look on https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

Comment: Thank you Thomas fo your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that chrome plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Install it, activate it and refresh the view.

It will a least let you work without that Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue.
It would be good if someone bring the fix but directly in the code...